# Laravel Eloquent get parent relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have a model "Invoice".
This model has a hasMany relation to model "InvoiceLine".

```
public function invoiceLines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\InvoiceLine');
}
```

I want to display all prices in the right currency (like $ 23.59 and € 52,33) of a couple of invoices (simplified)

```
$invoices = Invoice::where(........)->with('invoiceLines')->get();
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    foreach ($invoice->invoiceLines as $line) {
        echo $line->formattedPrice();
    }
}
```

Therefor the model "InvoiceLine" has a method "formattedPrice"

```
public function formattedPrice()
{
    $invoice = ?????;
    $currency = $invoice->currency;
    $price = $this->price;

    return formatPrice($price, $currency);
}
```

But i can not figure out how to get the currency attribute from the invoiceLine's parent "invoice".

Answer (score 1):

In your `InvoiceLine.php` model add the inverse relationship.

```
public function invoice()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class);
}
```

Now you can access your invoice like so.

```
$invoice = $this->invoice;
$currency = $invoice->currency;
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. When i do that i create a N+1 problem because Laravel wil then get the invoice belonging to the invoiceline for each invoiceline.

Comment: Then you need to include it using with('invoiceLines.invoice'), that is the tradeoff when you do active records

Answer (score -1):

You can split the totals as follows

```
$euro_total = 0;
$usd_total = 0;
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
foreach ($invoice->invoiceLines as $line) {

        if($invoice->currency == 'EURO'){
            $euro_total = $euro_total + $line->price;
        }
        if($invoice->currency == 'USD'){
            $usd_total = $euro_total + $line->price;
        }

    }
}
echo $euro_total;
echo $usd_total;
```